# Pointing Existing featured images to s3 bucket

Tags: post-thumbnails

Our wordpress site is moved to another server and we moved all the images to amazon s3. Updated the post_content and guid to s3 path. On verifying found that the images which are set as featured images are not displaying since it still refers to the site url path. Although giving the define('upload') in the config file fix this issue, it then shows error while making a new upload.               I am using plugin amazon s3 and cloudfront plugin for uploading to s3 bucket. How can I fix this so that my newly images upload to s3 and my existing featured images point to s3?
thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic, also don't change the guid. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Please link to the plugins you are using, although you are probably better of inquiring with their developers since it seems to have little to do with WP itself.